# Fourier Series of product of two functions with different period

Tags: fourier-series, convolution

I am working on analyzing special electrical circuits in frequency domain. So I need to be able to have the product of several functions represented as Fourier series.

Suppose we have two periodic functions and we know their Fourier series:

$$
f(t) \sim\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}F_n e^{i n \frac{2 \pi}{T_f} t}\\
g(t) \sim\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}G_n e^{i n \frac{2 \pi}{T_g} t}
$$

what is the Fourier series coefficients of $h(t)=f(t)\cdot g(t)$?

I know when $T_f = T_g$, it is their convolution

$$
H_n = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}F_m\cdot G_{n-m}=F_n*G_n
$$

But in this case

$$
h(t) \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{F_{n}G_{m} e^{i 2 \pi \left( \frac{n}{T_f}+\frac{m}{T_g} \right) t}}}
$$

I would like to know the amplitude of each frequency but working this way I have to find several terms and sum them. I have to solve the equation $\frac{n}{T_f}+\frac{m}{T_g}=f_h ,\quad \{n,m\}\in \mathbb{Z}$ then add them all up. It would be better to have $H_n$ and have the sum without the need for solving a equation for each.

Comment: If $T_f/T_g$ is rational, use the least common multiple of $T_f$ ans $T_g$. Otherwise, $f+g$ is NOT periodic unless $f$ or $g$ is constant.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I know what you are getting at, let $T_h = T_f T_g$ then the power of e will be $i \pi \frac{n T_f + m T_g}{T_h}t$ but the problem is there are many of (n,m) leading to the same $n T_f + m T_g$ I would like to know if there is some way to find them easily

Comment: If $T_f/T_g = p/q$ where $p,q$ are relatively prime positive integers, then f+g$ has period $qT_f=pT_g$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan with your help I have come so far $\sum_{n}{\sum_{m}{F_{n}G_{m}e^{i2 \pi t \left( \frac{n q + m p}{T_{h}} \right)}}}$ how should I perform the change of variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $T_f/T_g$ is rational $p/q$, where $p,q$ are positive integers. Then $T := qT_f=pT_g$ is a common period. The Fourier series   of $f$ and $g$ can be written
$$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{i2\pi nt/T} \text{ and } \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} b_n e^{i2\pi nt/T},$$
where $a_{qk}=:F_k$ and $b_{pk}:=G_k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the other coefficients are $0$.
Then you need only to make a convolution of the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ thus defined.

Comment: Let me know if I understood correctly. So first we will take the common period to define Fourier series of the two functions. And the old coefficients will spread apart q-1 and p-1 respectively in the new series. for example if $F_n=F_0,F_1,F_2,...$ and $q=3$ then $a_n=F_0,0,0,F_1,0,0,F_2,0,0,...$

Comment: Yes, it is what happens.